# How to fix Alt+7 bullet point • alt code not working?

Tags: windows-10, alt-code

Before I reinstalled Windows a week ago, I could type bullet point(•) symbol by pressing Alt+7 on the numpad. The previous version of Windows I was on is 1709, now I'm on 21H2. Now after I reinstalled Windows, I couldn't type any Alt codes whatsoever. I googled it and people suggested to set `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` registry key to 1. I did and now I can type some alt codes like before, for example Alt+0176 for degrees works: °. But the bullet point symbol still doesn't work. How to make it work again?

The system language is English and the keyboard layout is English(US), too:
[image]

Comment: For me, Alt+7 only works using the 7 key in the numpad. Did you try it?

Comment: @harrymc yes, that's what I said: I press Alt+7 on the numpad.

Comment: I test this on my Desktop with NumPad (Windows 11) and Alt-7 does not work there either.

Comment: It seems to work for me and not for others. Strange. Check this : (1) [Mouse Keys](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103553-how-turn-off-mouse-keys-windows-10-a.html) are disabled, (2) In *Control Panel > region > Administrative > Change system locale...* that is unchecked "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support".

Comment: @harrymc I applied both things and I still can't Alt+7 to enter bullet point.

Comment: Have you rebooted ? Otherwise, I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted.

Comment: Getting the same issue, I started to having this problem from a month ago, after some of the recent updates I guess (Windows 10 here). Surprisingly to me I'm not the one getting used to this ALT+7 hotkey and having this problem. Unfortunately no solution available yet.